# Quand parle-t-on de grains et quand parle-t-on de graines ?

Tags: vocabulaire, étymologie, origine-ou-raison, synonymes, alimentation

Comme en français nous avons les mots *grain* et *graine*, je me suis posé la question de savoir quand utiliser l'un ou l'autre.

C'est peut-être une erreur mais il me semble que les grains ont plus de rapport à la cuisine et sa préparation tandis que les graines semblent être plus utilisées pour la culture, l'agriculture,…

Est-ce une interprétation correcte ? Avec une étymologie sans doute similaire, en quoi ces deux mots diffèrent-ils ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

« Grain » vient du latin *granum* (de l'indo-européenne °ger- )*, mot masculin singulier. Le pluriel neutre de *granum* est *grana* qui a aussi été employé comme féminin et a donné « graine » en français.

Le **grain**  désigne « le fruit comestible des graminées », il est parfois aussi utilisé pour désigner la semence, c'est-à-dire pour assurer la reproduction de l'espèce.

**Graine** appartient au champ lexical de la biologie et désigne « la partie des plantes à fleur qui permet d'assurer la reproduction ».

Un grain de blé, qu'on peut consommer, est aussi la graine qui va assurer la reproduction de la plante. Mais je ne pense pas que les deux mots soient toujours interchangeables. Je ne suis pas biologiste mais je soupçonne que tous les grains ne sont pas propices à la reproduction, donc ne seraient pas qualifiés de « graines ».  Et une graine d'un végétal non comestible ne peut pas être consommée, donc elle ne sera pas qualifié de grain.

Source : *Dictionnaire culturel en langue française* (sld Alain Rey)

<sub>*A aussi donné le germanique *°kurnam* (anglais *corn*, allemand *Korn*)</sub>

Comment: OK pour l'ambiguité grain/graine, mais quid du grain de sable par exemple ?

Comment: @LaurentS. … vous avez vu des *grains de sable* se reproduire autrement que par l'érosion ? (Vous la planter où, votre *graine de sable* pour qu'elle croisse et se multiplie ? :-)

Answer (score 9):

*Grain* se rapporte plus à l'individualité et l'apparence (petit, dur) tandis que *graine* se rapporte plus à la généricité et la finalité (semences, reproduction):

- Grain de riz, de maïs mais aussi au sens figuré de sable, de sel, de poussière.
- Graine: plantes à graines, mauvaise graine, graine de violence, la petite graine ...

Ces doublons sont très rarement interchangeables.

Answer (score 3):

En fait cette différence est simple : le grain est le fruit entier de la plante tandis que la graine se trouve elle-même dans le grain. Exemple de celle de la mangue c'est le grain qu'on mange et la graine à jeter, mais pour les céréales, ce n'est pas possible de les différencier à l'œil nu, donc c'est le grain qui est en même temps la graine.

Je suis un étudiant de l'Université de Niamey à la fac d'agro.

Answer (score 2):

> - *Graine* : partie des plantes à fleur qui assure leur reproduction ; ovule fécondé de la fleur : la graine est contenue dans le fruit, on plante une graine.

Elle est considérée comme une semence, chaîne du vivant.

> - *Grain* : fruit comestible des graminées : grain d'orge, de blé, d'avoine ...

Il est considéré comme une céréale consommable, base de toutes les grandes civilisations.

<sup>Références extraites du petit Robert</sup>